# Start arguments for Windows Background Service in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, background-service

I am making a Windows Service using .NET's `BackgroundService` abstract class (similar to the one in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service) by Microsoft) but I can't seem to figure out how to get start arguments passed to the service using the Windows Services app. Can someone tell me how to get the arguments I pass in there or what I should be doing?

Comment: Environment.GetCommandLineArgs

Comment: @shingo But that only gives me the arguments used by Windows to start the service, what about user start parameters specified in the services app [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBDgY.png)?

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass through the args from `Main`:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(options =>
        {
            options.ClearProviders();
            options.AddEventLog();
            options.AddConsole();
        })
        .UseWindowsService(options =>
        {
            options.ServiceName = "WorkerServiceTestArgs";
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton(new MyArgsService(args));
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        })
        .Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

Your worker then has a dependency on your service:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly MyArgsService _myArgsService;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, MyArgsService myArgsService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _myArgsService = myArgsService;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            _logger.LogInformation("Args: {args}", string.Join(";", _myArgsService.GetArgs()));

            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

e.g. with this simple Service:

```
public class MyArgsService
{
    private readonly string[] _args;

    public MyArgsService(string[] args)
    {
        _args = args;
    }

    public string[] GetArgs()
    {
        return _args;
    }
}
```

Results:

[image: Windows service config]

[image: Event log]

Comment: How did you pass in the args? Did you add the service to Windows using service control (sc.exe) or using Powershell's New-Service command?

Comment: In my case with PS: `New-Service -Name "WindowsServiceTestArgs" -Path "<mypath...>\WindowsServiceTestArgs.exe firstArg SecondArg"`

Comment: Hmm, okay I thought binPath or Path argument was only for the path of the service executable and not for passing parameters but I guess I was wrong, I will try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a class derived from `ServiceBase` to receive parameters and implement `IHostLifetime`.

```
public class MyServiceLifetime : ServiceBase, IHostLifetime
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    public public Task WaitForStartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => Task.CompletedTask;
    
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Replace this class with `UseWindowsService`.

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHostLifetime, MyServiceLifetime>();
        services.AddSingleton<JokeService>();
        services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
    })
    .Build();
```

Comment: Is `WindowsServiceLifetime` [still applicable for .NET 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.windowsservices.windowsservicelifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#applies-to)?

Comment: [ServiceBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) is applicable for .NET 5+, so the class can inherit from it.